# How to calculate width of text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to get the width of the text.

```
var e=document.createElement('span');
          e.style.fontSize = scope.fontsize;
          e.innerHTML = "test";
          console.log(e.offsetWidth);
```

Width always comes as 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have to append the created element to the `document`.

```
var e=document.createElement('span');
document.body.appendChild(e);
e.style.fontSize = 14;
e.innerHTML = "test";
console.log(e.offsetWidth);
e.remove();
```

Output: 23

---

Hiding the element does not work ether.

```
 e.style.display= "none";
```

Output: 0

---

To "hide it" you could add a CSS like that. But with the added  `remove()` it will likely not show up anyway. But adding `position:absolute;` is a good idea, since this will prevent flickering of the rest of the html content.

```
   position:absolute;
   margin-left:-1000em;
```

Comment: you can also add a css class to hide it if you just need width and want to really display it

Comment: It seems like the width is only calculated when the element is actually displayed.

Comment: It is creating blank span tag at the end can't we delete those

Comment: e.remove() at the end